# How do I get rid of Konsole's random annoying transparent 1px lines?

Tags: kde, display, plasma, konsole, high-dpi

I'm using the latest versions of Konsole and KDE with Plasma on Arch. It's been an issue since forever. I have random 1px thick transparent lines showing up all over the place. I want to get rid of them. I'm using a 4k monitor, forced to 105 DPI font at 1.5x global zoom. I've seen that https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=373232 may be causing it, but that issue was supposedly fixed a while back, and my lines are also vertical. Please don't ask me to change DPI, scaling, or my monitor. Thanks!
[image: Sample of what I see. white lines here, because of white window behind konsole.]

Comment: Is this problem limited to Konsole only? Or does this issue exist with other terminal emulators as well?

Comment: @Bananguin As far as I can see after extensive testing it's only Konsole.